# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.validators.bar._xaxis' when using plotly

Tags: matplotlib, plotly-python

I am trying to plot graphs using the Plotly library. where the x-axis is "interval" and two y-axes " y1-sum " and "y2-average" but I am getting below error.

ERROR:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-418-27dc9ac84c2a> in <module>
      1 from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
      2 fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
----> 3 fig.add_trace(fig1.data[0], secondary_y=False)
      4 fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0], secondary_y=True)
      5 fig.update_layout(width=700, height=450, hovermode='x')
 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.validators.bar._xaxis'
```

The code I am using is as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/y1_data.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/y2_data.csv')

fig1 =go.Figure([go.Bar(x=df2['Interval'], y=df1['sum'], name='iops')])
fig2 =go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=df2['Interval'], y=df2['Average'], name='latency')])

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(fig1.data[0], secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0], secondary_y=True)
fig.update_layout(width=700, height=450, hovermode='x')
fig.show()
```

[image]
Need Graph like above.
[sample_data_iops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNc7p.png)
[sample_data_lat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfggx.png)

Currently using Plotly 4.x version. Can anyone let me know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following code with the understanding that your question was intended to draw two axes in one graph, rather than multiple graphs. I don't have sample data, so I haven't been able to check the execution in my environment, but you can specify the graph and the y-axis at the same time. Please refer to [this](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#two-y-axes).

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/y1_data.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/y2_data.csv')

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(x=df2['Interval'], y=df1['sum'], name='io_rate data'),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df2['Interval'], y=df2['Average'], name='latency data'),
    secondary_y=True,
)

fig.update_layout(width=700, height=450, hovermode='x')
    
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>primary</b> io_rate", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>secondary</b> latency", secondary_y=True)
    
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @ r-beginners again getting module not found error. I have tried that what u have specified in link... will attach the sample data...

Comment: There are some caveats in your code. The library name is written in uppercase, but generally it is in lowercase, as in my code. Try lowercasing your code first.

Comment: while editing in StackOverflow it got changed. Originally if I execute anything with the upper case it throws an error. The above script is executed with all lower case and where ever the upper case is necessary I have used upper case

Comment: The graph was displayed correctly in both your code and mine. Is there a problem with your environment, or is plotly up to date? I am on `Plotly 4.14.3`.

Comment: What I have added is the image obtained by running your code.

Comment: i am using plotly version 4.5.2. WIll try with the 4.14.3 version once

Comment: got the graph after replacing the version of plotly

Comment: It was an environmental problem, after all. If my answer is worthy of acceptance, please accept it.